# How to get the depth level at a any given level in the template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-mptt

**Setup:**

- a tree structure of the models.
- a representation of that structure in the HTML.

**Issue:**

How to know at any given recursion level the depth level at which currently I am?

**Example:**

This is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        0

        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>0</li>
</ul>
```

0,1 are the children's depth level that I want to get at any given time.

Comment: you mean like UML Diagram of models?

Comment: @doniyor See the added example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the template variable `node.level` and it will give you the indentation level.

You can read more about it at:

http://django-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/technical_details.html?highlight=level#level

Comment: Was about to post this, and just to clarify since mptt is only mentioned in a tag here. This applies to django-mptt models, ususally traversed with one of its template tags.